# Does bottleneck size matter in Disentangled Variational Autoencoders?

Tags: variational-autoencoder, latent-variable, bottlenecks

I suppose that picking an appropriate size for the bottleneck in Autoencoders is neither a trivial nor an intuitive task. After watching this [video about VAEs](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9zKuYvjFFS8), I've been wondering: Do disentangled VAEs solve this problem?

After all, if the network is trained to use as few latent space variables as possible, I might as well make the bottleneck large enough so that I don't run into any issues during training. Am I wrong somewhere?